# PIL: add a text at the bottom middle of image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, fonts, python-imaging-library

I've width and height of the image.

```
img = Image.open(img_src)
width, height = img.size

font = ImageFont.truetype("MuseoSansCyrl_0.otf", 100)
text_w, text_h = draw.textsize(title, font)
```

I'm trying to find a generic way to add a text to image at the bottom middle.

Here is the function I've wrote:

```
def process_img(img_src, title, background):

    img = Image.open(img_src, 'r')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    w, h = img.size

    font = ImageFont.truetype("MuseoSansCyrl_0.otf", 100)
    text_w, text_h = draw.textsize(title, font)

    draw.text((REQ_WIDTH, REQ_HEIGHT), title, (255,255,255), font=font)

    img.save(img_src)

    return img_src
```

Is there any way I can get the REQ_WIDTH and REQ_HEIGHT ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had already placed a call to `draw.textsize`, which returns you the Width and Height the final text will have - from that point, you just thave to calculate the top-left corner where to render your text like this:

Top will be your image_height  - text_height, left will be your image_width/2 - text_width / 2 - thus, your rendering call becomes simply:

```
draw.text(((w - text_w) // 2, h - text_h), title, (255,255,255), font=font)
```

(Note that `draw.text` includes an optional "anchor"  argument - but the possible values for it are not documented, nor the documentation states whether it is actually implemented. If it *is* implemented, and there is a value that represents (horizontal_center, bottom) as the Anchor, you should only have to pass the image_width / 2 and image_height, without needing to call `draw.textsize`)

Comment: if my title is longer than the image itself won't it mess up ? Is there a way I can wrap a text so it looks fine ? for Example: ** Game Of Thrones The Battle Of Bastards **

Answer (score 4):

The names you have for the needed variables — `REQ_WIDTH` and `REQ_HEIGHT` — are a little misleading because they're not a width and height, they are the "**xy** anchor coordinates of the text" relative to its top left corner by default — see [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text) — in other words, its position.

You just need to do a little math:

```
    X_POSN = h - text_h
    Y_POSN = w//2 - text_w//2  # Or (w - text_w) // 2

    draw.text((X_POSN, Y_POSN), title, (255,255,255), font=font)
```

Comment: If my title is longer than the image itself won't it mess up ?
Is there a way I can wrap a text so it looks fine ?

for Example:
**
    Game Of Thrones
 The Battle Of Bastards
**

Comment: If the calculated x position is negative then the string is too long to fit. You could reduce the `font` size until it does or perhaps use the [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#module-textwrap) module to word-wrap it — although the latter assumes all the characters are the same width, something which would only be true for [monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samples_of_monospaced_typefaces) (but not Museo Sans).

Comment: I can do a text wrap but I wanted the textlines not to exceed more than 2.

Comment: Just break the string into two on the word boundary nearest the center.

Comment: Is there a way I can add text shadow text opacity, spacing etc ?
because draw.text doesn't offer all these. I want to use the following properties on the text lines on the image [http://www.melanieceraso.com/psd-to-css3/#]

Comment: You could simulate many of them using multiple `draw.text` calls in conjunction with some of the other image processing capabilities PIL offers. There are third party tools out there with Python bindings, like [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)'s PythonMagick, that are more powerful.